# Get solid version of colour with alpha value while considering colour underneath

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicolor

Say I have a background view with a gradient and I add a `UITableView` on top of this. I then have `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews` with a background colour featuring an alpha value. For example:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
```

The background colour then changes based on the part of the gradient that it is currently scrolled above. This is the behaviour I desire, however because of the sticky header native-iOS behaviour, the cells scroll underneath the transparent view.

Therefore, I need a way to get a solid version of a colour with an alpha value based on the colour underneath. So if I had the above example colour above a blue gradient background, I would get a slightly darker colour than is underneath.

Anyone know how to do this? This was a difficult one to explain so feel free to ask for any clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to add a `UIBlurView` to your `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews`. In this way the background color of your `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews` is still going to adapt depending on what is underneath it but the `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews` are still going to be readable.

Another option would be to not use `UITableViewHeaderFooterViews` (if you don't need their "sticky header native-iOS behaviour" and instead create a custom cell and use it only for your row 0.